# Optimize trie implementation to search autocomplete

Tags: javascript, json, trie

I have a project in which let the user to lookup for countries in a json file,
i've changed the structure of my json file from:

```
{
"AE": {"name": "United arab emirates","alternate": "UAE"},
"GB": {"name": "United kingdom","alternate": "Great Britain England","weight": "2.5"},
"US": {"name": "United states","alternate": "USA United States of America","weight": "3.5"},
.........
}
```

to this structure:

```
var countries = {
"name": "United arab emirates","alternate": "UAE",
"name": "United kingdom","alternate": "Great Britain England","weight": "2.5",
"name": "United states","alternate": "USA United States of America","weight": "3.5",
.........
}
```

but i couldn't figure how to edit the js code right to work with the json new structure,

here is the my code:
countries.js :

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  // var log = console.log.bind(console);
  // No timing in IE (sucker)
  if(!console.time) {
    console.time = console.timeEnd = function() {};
  }
  var countries, index;
  function indexData() {
    index = new T.Index({
      'name' :'countries',
      'indexSubstring': false,
      'intersectResults': true
    });
    console.time('loading');
    index.load(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.time('indexing');
        Object.keys(countries).forEach(function(id) {
          var country = countries[id];
          var toIndex = [country.name , country.alternate].join(' ');
          index.add(id, toIndex, country.weight || 1);
        });
        console.timeEnd('indexing');
        console.time('saving');
        index.save(function() {
          console.timeEnd('saving');
        });
      }
      else {
        // Already loaded
        window.index = index;
        console.timeEnd('loading');
      }
    });
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === 4) {
      // Break the cyclic reference
      request.onreadystatechange = null;
      if (typeof request.responseText === "string") {
        try {
          countries = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        } catch(e) {
          // do something
        }
        // Index, if data was loaded
        if(countries) {
          indexData();
        }
      }
    }
  };
  request.open('get', 'data/countries.json', true);
  request.send();
  var search = document.getElementById('search');
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  var lastVal;
  function lookup() {
    var query = search.value;
    if(lastVal === query) {
      return;
    }
    // Time the lookup
    console.time('lookup: ' + query);
    var ids = index.search(query);
    console.timeEnd('lookup: ' + query);
    // render the list
    results.innerHTML = ids.map(function(id) {
      var country = countries[id];
      return '<li rel="' + id + '">' + country.name + '</li>';
    }).join('');
    lastVal = query;
  }
  search.addEventListener('keyup', lookup, false);
}).call(null);
```

countries.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trie.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <!--- trie-structure implementation ---->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wunderlist/trie.js/master/dist/trie.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Type in a country name</label>
  <input id="search" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" />
  <ul id="results" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/countries.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: 
am also trying to limit the result to 5 suggestions. but i am stuck too.

please help thanks.

Comment: Your new structure is no valid JSON any more. Did you mean to use an array?

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly .

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want to change with your search? It uses triejs library to build a tree structure, based on your json file, and triejs's search method to find the results based on the input. It looks like it works.

To limit the output you could slightly change your map function like this, for example:

```
results.innerHTML = ids.map(function(id, i) {
  var country = countries[id];
  if (i < 5) {
     return '<li rel="' + id + '">' + country.name + '</li>';
  }
 }).join('');
```

Comment: i want to get rid of countries[id] coz its useless in my case  @stee1rat

Comment: @EileenLorant do you mean you want get rid of Trie.js? If so - you still need to get a valid json and get rid of `var countries =` in countries.json and then filter the results yourself.